# What's this window position called?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

If there is even the English name for this, please tell me. [image]

Comment: I'd probably just describe it as "tilted open"

Comment: It looks like an open transom.

Comment: @HotLicks it's a transom window.  (Transoms in this case are the strengthening pieces of wood above the top of the door.)

Comment: @user888379 yes, because that's what it is, without the connotation that "being ajar" brings.

Comment: If there wasn't a descriptive word for that before, I bet there's a legal word for that in covid times; you can't go back to school without operable and opened windows.

Comment: An **open** "hopper" casement window

Comment: @Hotlicks is right. That's called a "transom." A "transom" is a window above a door. Transoms that are installed above interior doors, like that one is, are to allow ventilation between rooms without having to have the door open. You could say that the "transom is tilted open," but since every transom I've ever seen only tilts open, if you call it a "transom," I'd think saying that the "transom is open" should be sufficient. Still, in answer to your question, I might describe that position by saying something like, "The open transom tilted into the room from the top about 20 degrees."

Comment: A hopper transom window 'open to its full extent' (disregarding abuse).

Comment: Do you want a name for this type of opening? It's "open". But if you are interested in knowing the name of this horizontal window, which reminds me of a flap then Hot Licks has the answer. I just know within a week I'll forget its name "transom window" and call it either a *trans**form** window* or a *window flap* (totally wrong, and misleading but who knew that thing had a proper name?!)

Comment: It's also sometimes called a "bottom hung" window, meaning it hinges at the bottom. But the questioner needs to be more specific. https://www.archiexpo.com/prod/giesse/product-2527-767651.html

Comment: Note that someone might say that the window is *cocked open*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are looking for "hopper window". It opens at the top, as opposed the more common "awning window" that opens at the bottom.

[Pros and Cons of Hopper and Awning Replacement Windows](https://www.signaturewindow.com/blog/pros-and-cons-of-hopper-and-awning-replacement-windows/#:%7E:text=What%20are%20Hopper%20and%20Awning,or%20pull%20inward%20to%20open.)

> Awning windows hinge at the top and push outward to open. When the window is open the glass pane creates a little roof over the opening. Hopper windows are similar, except they hinge at the bottom and can push outward or pull inward to open.

It's not a term or distinction that a lot of people need to know, though.